# Animate, Jump Position, Animate

Tags: jquery, animation

Can this animation loop be done more efficiently? I am trying to get .gameBoxContent to slide left and then slide in from the right. The content of the box changes during this animation.

Basically the div should:

1: slide left out of view

2: Jump Right

3: slide left into view

```
// Slide Left
$('.gameBoxContent').animate( {"left": "-950px"}, 400);

// Sure this can be done better
$('.gameBoxContent').animate( {"top": "950px"}, 1);
$('.gameBoxContent').animate( {"left": "960px"}, 0);
$('.gameBoxContent').animate( {"top": "20px"}, 1);

// Slide Right
$('.gameBoxContent').animate( {"left": "20px"}, 400);
```

Comment: _"Can this animation loop be done more efficiently?"_ Can define "more efficiently" ? One option may be to "chain" `.animation()` calls to single , initial `$(".gameBoxContent").animation(options).animation(options)` ?

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of removing the need to slide down and around. Trying to make the element jump to right after sliding left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `top` animations ; setting element `.css("left", window.innerWidth + $(this).width())` to right of viewport at `complete` callback of initial .`animation({left:-950})` ; utilize one function pattern returned from within `$.map()` loop ; set as `this` object as `.gameBoxContent` within `.animate()` ; apply `options` of `settings` object as parameters to `.animate()`

```js
var settings = [
  [{
    "left": "-950px"
  }, {
    duration: 400,
    complete: function() {
      $(this).css("left", window.innerWidth + $(this).width())
    }
  }],
  [{
    "left": "20px"
  }, {
    duration: 400
  }]
];


$(".gameBoxContent").queue("_fx", $.map(settings, function(options, i) {
  return function(next) {
    return $(this).animate.apply($(this), options).promise().then(next)
  }
})).dequeue("_fx");
```

```css
.gameBoxContent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gameBoxContent"></div>
```